# Sharing specific text on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I have a quiz page, where the outcome can be 1 of 10 possibilities. 
I then have a share link for Facebook, to share a link to the page and also to share the results from the quiz.

I believe I could alter the og tags in the header so that og:description became the desired text, however as Facebook caches pages, this would only be correct the first time being shares and all other shares would be this same one and not the updates og:description tag.

Using JavaScript, is there any other way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Create a unique page for each result

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is not to change OG tags but use FB.ui

```
            var obj = {
                method: 'feed',
                picture: image.png,
                name: 'name text',
                caption: 'caption text',
                description: 'description',
                link: 'link',
            };

            function callback(response) {
                console.log("Post ID: " + response['post_id']);
            }
            FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

This is covered in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5 you will need a Facebook APP + FB JS in your HTML.